# How would I recreate glitchy vocals

Tags: vocals, glitch

I'm asking to see if anyone would know how would I go about to recreate the glitchy vocals at the 56 seconds where they said "ideality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a Bitcrusher effect (because I hear some distortion which sounds typical of those effects) but I'm not sure and it could be combined with something else (it also reminds me of some time-stretching resulting effect but time doesn't sound affected here).

Find a free (or paid, up to you ;) ) Bitcrusher effect, play with the parameters to see if you come close. You'd probably have to automate them to achieve more interesting dynamics.